# How Plot a bar Graph in python from Pivot Table() result?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, seaborn, data-visualization

I've calculated total Employees in company based on their ' Gender ' and ' Educational Background '. Now I want to visualize it in the form of bar plots , But I've tried to do , still I'm unable to view it visually .

Code :

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(comp2, index = ['Gender', 'EducationBackground'], aggfunc={'EducationBackground':'count'})
```

Result:

```
"""
                             EducationBackground
Gender  EducationBackground 
Female        Life Sciences                   30
                  Marketing                   15
                    Medical                   21
                      Other                    2
           Technical Degree                    7
  Male      Human Resources                    3
              Life Sciences                   48
                  Marketing                   14
                    Medical                   42
                      Other                    1
           Technical Degree                   11
```

Visualize :

```
sns.countplot(df1,hue='EducationBackground')
```

Error:

```
Could not interpret input 'EducationBackground'
```

Comment: try `hue=df1.EducationBackground`

Comment: You might be getting an error because the index name and the column name are the same, so why not change the column name?

Answer (score 2):

`sns.countplot` already performs an aggregation (similar to what you are doing in `pivot_table`), so you can probably obtain what you need by using `sns.countplot` directly on the `comp2` dataframe, something like:

```
sns.countplot(x='EducationBackground', hue="Gender", data=comp2)
```

NB: you can obtain a similar result by using `sns.barplot` on `df1`.

Comment: Yes @rjg it works and really helped me a lot . Thanks

Comment: Hi @Ali, if the answer indeed solves your problem, consider accepting the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers